# Load csv file with R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to load a csv file with R This csv file contains only one column. When I try to do :

```
Data <- read.csv ("file.csv", header = FALSE)
```

It loads also the id-row : 1, 2, ...

How can I do to load only the value?

Thank you

the csv file :

```
123

11 

24 

122 

133
```

I would like to load 123, 11 ,24, 122 and 133 in  one variable
when I try to do a histogram with : 
hist(X, xlim = c(-10, 20))
it indicates

```
x must be numeric
```

Comment: Does it load it or is it just printed? In R, data.frames have row names which are, by default, simply 1, 2, ...n

Comment: Can you please give a small portion of your csv, along with your current output and expected output? There isn't much to go off of here.

Comment: @MikeJewski edit thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the column with the variables, because x is a dataframe.

```
hist(x$V1,xlim=c(-10,20))
```

or just take the column as a vector

```
x <- read.csv("file.csv",header=FALSE)[,1]
hist(x,xlim=c(-10,20))
```

Answer (score 0):

Print '`head(Data)`' and `str(Data)`. Have you id-row now?

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer in order to help the asker

Comment: It's about "It loads also the id-row : 1, 2, ...How can I do to load only the value?" But asker have already decided the problem.